# Where can I read info about the linux-image-5.17.0-1015-oem kernel package?

Tags: kernel, 22.04

Where can I read info about the linux-image-5.17.0-1015-oem kernel package? Particularly, I am looking for changes comparing with 5.17.0-1014-oem.

Comment: basic detail can be found at https://packages.ubuntu.com/ and search to https://packages.ubuntu.com/jammy/linux-image-5.17.0-1015-oem then changelog at 
https://changelogs.ubuntu.com/changelogs/pool/main/l/linux-signed-oem-5.17/linux-signed-oem-5.17_5.17.0-1015.16/changelog

Comment: Thanks. It is not too much.